# How to use a map function insted of a Loop Python

Tags: python, django

I am working on django project. I would like to avoid use Loop because of a number of row in the file to upload.

> With a loop, I have this (it's nicely working with small files):

```
my_list = []
for ligne in my_json:
    network = Network(
        x1=ligne["x1"],
        x2=ligne.get("x2", None),
        x3=ligne.get("x3", None),
    )
    my_list.append(network)
```

I try to use python map fucntion like:

```
my_map = map(
    lambda x: (x["x1"],
        x.get("x2"),
        x.get("x3")), my_json)
list(my_map)
```

How can I do that with map

Comment: You never use `Network`, you just want `map(lambda ligne: Network(ligne['x1'], x2=ligne.get("x2"), x3=ligne.get("x3"), my_json)`? Anyway, you should probably just use a list comprehension

Comment: What data type is `ligne`? Is it a `dict`?

Comment: What do you expect from using `map`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [
    Network(
        x1=ligne["x1"],
        x2=ligne.get("x2", None),
        x3=ligne.get("x3", None),
    ) for ligne in my_json
]
```

You can technically do this with `map`, but it's not any more efficient, and is less idiomatic.  It would look like this:

```
my_list = list(map(
    lambda ligne: Network(
        x1=ligne["x1"],
        x2=ligne.get("x2", None),
        x3=ligne.get("x3", None),
    ),
    my_json
))
```